# Proof and explanation about Trigonometric Identity

Tags: trigonometry

I would like to know about the following identities:
$$sec^2\theta-tan^2\theta=1; cosec^2\theta-cot^2\theta=1$$
Both identities are not true for all values of $\theta$.
My point is if the following is true:
$$sec^2\theta-tan^2\theta=1; |sec\theta|\geq1$$
$$\forall\theta\in\mathbb{R}-\{(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}, n\in\mathbb{I} \} $$
and
$$cosec^2\theta-cot^2\theta=1; |cosec\theta|\geq1$$
$$\forall\theta\in\mathbb{R}-     \{n\pi, n\in\mathbb{I} \} $$

Comment: For the one with secant & tangent, the excluded values of $\theta$ should be the odd multiples of $\pi/2$, that is, $(2n+1)(\pi/2)$. These are the places where $\cos\theta=0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for your reply. But I would like to know if $n$ could be an integer, once, for example, $sin^2x=0$ when $x=\pi n$, for any integer $n$ .

Comment: Yes, that's what happens with the one with cosecant and cotangent.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Thank you for your answer and sorry for replying to you again. My teacher  presented it, but I still don't understand why $n\in \mathbb{I}  $

Comment: You start with $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$. Either you can divide by $\sin^2\theta$ to get $\csc^2\theta-\cot^2\theta=1$, or else $\sin^2\theta=0$, which is the same as $\sin\theta=0$, which is the same as $\theta$ is a multiple of $\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both identities are obtained by dividing the canonical identity
$$\cos^2\theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$$
by either $\cos^2 \theta$ or $\sin^2 \theta$ on both sides. The reason the expressions you describe are ill-defined is because $\cos^2 \theta$ or $\sin^2 \theta$ could be zero, exactly at the values you describe.